# what is the effect of `-1` before a string?

Tags: kdb

I am learning q. I have seen the following line

```
.log.info:{[x] -1 (string .z.T),":",x}
```

what is the effect of `-1` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ‘-1’ prints the string to the stdout (like Cathal's answer says :) )

But additionally the minus sign on the ‘-1’ means ‘-1’ will be printed on a new line in the stdout output e.g.

```
q) .log.info["abc"]
14:45:30.127:abc
-1
```

If there was no minus sign, there would be a ‘1’ appended with no space to the end of the string e.g.

```
q) .log.info["abc"]
14:45:30.127:abc1
```

Answer (score 1):

It prints the string to stdout. See this link from the KX wiki for more information.

https://code.kx.com/q/basics/handles/#file-stdout-stderr